# fetching more user details in twitter

Tags: php, twitter

I'm trying to fetch user's details from twitter using php, I have this working code:

```
  <?php
  require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');
  /** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
  $settings = array(
'oauth_access_token' => "",
'oauth_access_token_secret' => "",
'consumer_key' => "",
'consumer_secret' => ""
  );
  $url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";
  $requestMethod = "GET";
  if (isset($_GET['user'])) {$user = $_GET['user'];} else {$user = "";}
  if (isset($_GET['count'])) {$count = $_GET['count'];} else {$count = 1;}
  $getfield = "?screen_name=$user&count=$count";
  $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
  $string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
  ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
  ->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);
  if($string["errors"][0]["message"] != "") {echo "<h3>Sorry, there was a problem.</h3><p>Twitter returned the following error message:</p><p><em>".$string[errors][0]["message"]."</em></p>";exit();}
  foreach($string as $items)
{
    echo "Time and Date of Tweet: ".$items['created_at']."<br />";
    echo "Tweet: ". $items['text']."<br />";
    echo "Tweeted by: ". $items['user']['name']."<br />";
    echo "Screen name: ". $items['user']['screen_name']."<br />";
    echo "Followers: ". $items['user']['followers_count']."<br />";
    echo "Following: ". $items['user']['friends_count']."<br />";
}
  ?>
```

But I want to fetch more like location, bio, birthday, and so on. how to do this?

Comment: I think, these all information are provided by TWITTER. So, Place `print_r($string);die;` before `foreach($string as $items)` and see what information they are providing.

Comment: @NanaPartykar I did and got error...

Comment: What error? Paste that error here.

Comment: @NanaPartykar HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: This error came due to including this line or what?

Comment: @NanaPartykar yes I just added print_r($string);die; before foreach($string as $items) like you said and I got this

Comment: @NanaPartykar just worked! sorry

Comment: See there, all information’s are present.  *bio* will surely be present. Check and use all necessary information as how you are using `$items['user']['followers_count']`

Comment: @NanaPartykar THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR THE HELP!!!!

Comment: Most Welcome. *Enjoy*

Comment: @NanaPartykar Thanks! I have a small question, when I got array like this ( [profile_location] => Array ( [id] => 01bf5c1e56ac186d [url] => https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/01bf5c1e56ac186d.json [place_type] => unknown [name] => Riyadh [full_name] => Riyadh [country_code] => [country] => [contained_within] => Array ( ) [bounding_box] => [attributes] => Array ( ) )) how can I access the data inside of the array?

Comment: `$items['profile_location']['id'];`

Comment: @NanaPartykar didn't work :(